# Python - Convert string to list with same structure

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python string (`str`), which is `"['Fish & Chips', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']"`.

How can I convert this string to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: See [snakecharmerb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67957535/7954504) for a safer alternative to `eval()`.

---

It seems like you're looking for [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), which takes a string and evaluates it as a Python expression:

```
s = "['Fish & Chips', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']"

eval(s)
# ['Fish & Chips', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']

type(eval(s))
# list
```

Answer (score 1):

While `eval` works it's [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/5320906) to use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) if the input data is not trusted:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['Fish & Chips', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['Fish & Chips', 'Fast Food', 'Restaurants']
```